Grafana - Create variable with an array for each value
I would like to have an array for each variable value. The variable name is "Environment". For example:

Production : [applicationInsightsProductionConnectionString, otherResourceProductionConnectionString],Staging : [applicationInsightsStagingConnectionString, otherResourceStagingConnectionString]

This is not working of course. The goal is to be able to use the values inside each array.
If I change the value to:

Production : applicationInsightsProductionConnectionString,Staging : applicationInsightsStagingConnectionString

This works:

"${Environment.1.1}"
Also
"${Environment.1}"

I tried different formats of the "value" but without the correct behavior.

AFAIK, there is functional like this for variables in grafana: all variables are treated as strings and except for multi value formatting options no operations can change values output. Maybe something like chained variables can help?
